# How to put two lines to run in a if statement in a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, indentation, multiple-conditions

How to add two lines of code to run in a if statement in python 3 but still in one line?

What I am trying to do is that i have two lines of code

```py
print('Yes')
print('This is a dumb question')
```

And i have to run them in a if statement, like

```
if cat == "meow":
    print('Yes')
    print('This is a dumb question')
```

So i can do it in one line like

```
if cat == "meow":print('Yes')
```

Now i have to put the second print statement to the if statement while still maintaining it in 1 line, Can i do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html

Comment: Don’t. Python programmers have really strong ideas about code formatting, and what you’re doing has no advantage.

Comment: To my case actually, its the most beneficial thing ever made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if cat == "meow":print('Yes'); print('This is a dumb question')
```

Comment: Please consider selecting it as the right answer, if it solved your problem.

Comment: I will, S.O Doesnt allow marking answers correct before 10 minutes, so i will do it ASAP

Comment: Sure, now you would be able to do it. Thanks!